# What's wrong with this tree?

Tags: trees

I don't know what kind of tree it is - I think Madrona? This is in Seattle.

Its limbs are all gangly and now the leaves are dying off. Some of the upper leaves are getting black spots. What's wrong? What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in the world is the tree located?  Has anything changed about the tree's environment lately?

Comment: It's in Seattle. We have super soggy winters, with occasional freezing. Nothing changed lately, but the tree has not been getting any attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Don't think that it's a Madrone, the emerging shoots of madrones are reddish-pink in colour. These are rather green. If you've sought after it's berries, and they look like madrones- it more likely to be a strawberry tree (from the same family *Arbutus*). So they somewhat share similar diseases.

The cause of disease can be too much humidity owing to frost melting, or heavy rains. It can get worse if it's planted in a container outside.

The disease looks like a foliar blight. Foliar blight is a disease common to woody fruit plants like arbutus and apples. Deal with it by burning the affected branches and spraying thoroughly with copper Oxychloride. Expose the rotten roots (if there are any) and trim them off and allow the plant to grow new roots.

[Read more here:](https://www.arbutusarme.org/resources/diseases-and-pests/foliar-blight)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!